# Cocos2d (spacemanager) scale sprite to touch or projection guide line?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm applying an impulse to a sprite and I currently have an arrow behind the sprite to show which direction the sprite will be shot. But what I want to do is scale the arrow on its x axis to show the power of the impulse. How would I do this? I know how to scale on the x axis but how would I relate this to the touch, to do the impulse in using cgpoint in touchbegan and touchmoved. 
I want to do this OR
show a guide line that will show the path the sprite will travel when the touch has ended.
Thanks
I'm using spacemanager for the physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to scale the arrow to touch, I just got the distance between the touch, made it smaller and limited the scaling.
Heres my code

```
arrow.scaleX = ccpDistance(birdPosition, pt1)/50;
    if (arrow.scaleX > 1.0) {
        arrow.scaleX = 1.0;
    }
```

If anyone knows about the guide line Id still love to see that nd compare the two.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please show us your implementation of your guideline? would love to see it